# Remove Duplicate Attributes for a (Core) SINGLE-VALUE NO-USER-MODIFICATION Attribute in LDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I recently set up a FreeIPA server (4.9.8) on Centos and a replica. Somehow—I don't even know how this is possible—all of my groups have ended up with two identical sets of core attributes:

```
dn: cn=<group name>,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=<domain>,dc=com
modifiersName: cn=MemberOf Plugin,cn=plugins,cn=config
modifiersName: cn=MemberOf Plugin,cn=plugins,cn=config
```

I have tried to ldapmodify the attributes deleting or replacing the values; I've tried deleting the groups completely but whatever I try it throws an error complaining that a single-value attribute has multiple values. It might be compounded by the fact that almost all the groups also belong to another group so it's impossible to delete one without trying to make a modification to the membership of that main group and vice versa.

I found the attribute in the core schema for the directory and it is SINGLE-ATTRIBUTE NO-USER-MODIFICATION.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I see, modifiersName is a SINGLE-VALUE with NO-USERMODIFICATION. No chance to modify without delete object.

At least to query similar cases with multi Attributes with different (or same) values can can use the following awk script, if you like.
Firstly: you should export your objects in ad ldif file (REPORT.ldif)

```
grep '^dn:\|^cn:' REPORT.ldif | awk
'BEGINN {L1="",L2="";TYP="";DN_PREF="dn:";DN=""}
{ 
  if (TYP==$1) {
    printf("\n%s %s\n%s %s\n%s %s\n--------",
      DN_PREF,DN,
      $1,$2,
      L1,L2);
  }
  if (TYP==$1) {
    DN=$2;
  }
  L1=$1;
  L2=$2;
}'
```

Ouput:

```
dn ...
cn value1
cn value2
Cn ...
--------
dn ...
cn ...
cn ...
--------
...
```