# LDAP Search attribute with multiple occurence

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

i am looking for a ldap filter to find users who have an multi value attribute with duplicate values.

For example in this case i will find the users with duplicate {PersNumber}:

MVAttribute {PersNumber}111111
{PersNumber}111112

I tried many filters, but i could not find the right one yet.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which directory is your server? (OpenLDAP, Active Directory, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It is not an ldap search solution, but depeding on the number of users you could export the users in EXPORT.ldif and then apply an ldif awk solution in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74649357/remove-duplicate-attributes-for-a-core-single-value-no-user-modification-attri/75235694#75235694]. Hier is the modified awk script for duplicate Attribute **cn**

```
grep '^dn:\|^cn:' REPORT.ldif | awk
'BEGINN {L1="",L2="";TYP="";DN_PREF="dn:";DN=""}
{ 
  if (TYP==$1 && L2==$2) {
    printf("\n%s %s\n%s %s\n%s %s\n--------",
      DN_PREF,DN,
      $1,$2,
      L1,L2);
  }
  if (TYP==$1) {
    DN=$2;
  }
  L1=$1;
  L2=$2;
}'
```